# how to set cell's background color to any RGB value?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to set a cell background color to an RGB value like this

```
    XSSFCellStyle  instructionStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    instructionStyle.setWrapText(true);
    XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 73,144));
    instructionStyle.setFillForegroundColor(myColor);
    instructionStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

and even it compiles aside of being horizontally align to center there is no other effect on a cell's look.can someone tell me what's wrong with this code ?Thanks

Comment: See [quick-guide Fills and colors](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Fills+and+colors). Note the setting the [CellStyle.setFillPattern](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setFillPattern%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType%29). So for actual `apache poi` versions: `instructionStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);`. @apache-poi: Update your quick-guide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to add the following?

```
instructionStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Comment: Axel Richter has answered it in his comment. It's just the way this API works. The default fill pattern will not fill...